# Oracle maven dependency in bitbucket pipelines

Tags: oracle, maven, bitbucket

I had requested for Beta access to Bitbucket pipelines. I got confirmation for access today for one account. I enabled pipelines for account and tried to build one project with it. Project has oracle maven dependency. On my system, i have oracle dependency installed in local repo so it build fine.

How can I install oracle jar for pipelines to use for build ?

Comment: I have the same question. You can download `.jar` from Oracle maven repository but you need the Oracle account and store the secret key in the XML file.

Comment: I do have oracle account, Please let me know which secret key you are mentioning and how I can get it to put in xml file

Answer (score 0):

You cannot download the driver until you add your secure key to the settings.xml see https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/oracle_maven_repository_instructions_for.
How to generate the key is mentioned here https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/how_to_get_oracle_jdbc#settings

Then you can download the driver on your machine, but problem with Pipelines is still here. You cannot set this password there. I realized that I can use the Attlassian Maven repository for JDBC driver v6. For me, it is good enough.

This is my pom.xml.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Atlassian 3rd-Party</id>
        <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/3rdparty/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories> 
... 
<dependencies>   
<!-- Cannot download this: <dependency><groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId><artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId><version>12.1.0.2</version></dependency>-->
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.1-atlassian-hosted</version>
</dependency>
```

If you really need the JDBC7 driver you can manually download the driver from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html to your `lib` folder so it is accessible for your tests (the driver is runtime dependency).

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I don't want to add jar manually to lib folder. I want to use Pipelines to build as soon as code is committed on a branch.